# Facebook Login - JavaScript or PHP SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am at the stage where I am thinking of integrating a social login method into my site. Of course my first one will be the **facebook login** before moving onwards.

Basically my question is : **Which language is best for this type of OAuth connection, and which is going to let me do everything I want?**

This will encompass all OAuth connections in general eventually, but specifically Facebook for now.

From what I have read of the documentation, the JavaScript SDK allows you to login, and connect to the open graph API - which in turn will allow me to post / upload etc etc. This is also available in PHP.

**From experience which is the more durable route to go?**

***PHP or JAVASCRIPT***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and recommend way to authorize users is the JavaScript SDK ([FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/v2.2)). **No redirect needed (better usability), very easy to handle, no PHP needed (the new PHP SDK needs PHP 5.4+)**. Use PHP only for stuff that involves usage of the App Secret or Extended Access Tokens. And for cron jobs, obviously. You can even just forget about the PHP SDK and use your own CURL calls.

Btw, **security is no problem**, you should just activate "`appsecret_proof`" in the App Settings.

More information about `appsecret_proof`:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

One more reason (and one of the most important ones) is the **possibility to refresh Access Tokens (=User Sessions) easily without page refresh** by using [FB.getLoginStatus](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus).

And another reason is that you need to upgrade to new PHP SDK versions on your own. The JavaScript SDK does not need any upgrades, in the lase few years you only had to change one or two parameters in some cases, the SDK gets downloaded from the Facebook servers.

Also, if you add Social Plugins, you need the JavaScript SDK anyway.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR PHP/both

I'd really recommend PHP. You'll want to store the login in database. If you do it via JS, you'll need to make an Ajax call to the server, which is not really that secure.

Having said that, they are targeted for different uses. JS is for frontend more, while PHP is for backend (db storage, checks, actual  site login, etc). Using JS will let you generate the buttons on the fly, while using PHP you'll need to do some more coding.

Somehting else, the php library will get updated from time to time and you'll need to keep up after testing. JS also, but it's easier, since the code usually works.

If you only want one, use PHP. You can control what the code does and JS will not break your site since it's written by you. However, I'd recommend using both since you will probably want more than just simple login

Edit:
As facebook states, use PHP SDK: Usually this means you're developing with PHP for a Facebook Canvas app, **building your own website**, or **adding server-side functionality** to an app that already uses the Facebook SDK for JavaScript.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0

Comment: So you recommend building my own PHP / JavaScript hybrid? So the button works the same as on the JavaScript version yet I am using the PHP SDK and providing my own callbacks?

Comment: It very much depends on what you want to do. Pick up the php sdk if you only need login. If you want more, use both.

Comment: Using the PHP sdk you don't have to do anything with JS if you don't want specific user experience. You can do something like this: 1) generate login button. 2) when clicked, page redirect to facebook 3) when logged in, redirects back to your site with params in $_GET, 4) SDK will read that and tell you. 5) you log the user in using your own system

Comment: if you only need login, the PHP SDK is a very bad idea. it is so much easier (and recommended) with the JS SDK. also much more user friendly.

Comment: What I want to do is : **User click on button** => **MY JavaScript will detect the button has been pressed** => **Send a call to my PHP code using my own AJAX** => **PHP will deal with the authentication and saving details to the database** => **PHP will return a JSON response to my ORIGINAL JavaScript code** => **Original JavaScript will deal with the response**

Comment: My Only problem I can see with this one is that once the details are stored to the database - how does the user then login later on? Click on **Login with Facebook** and then because they have already authorized the APP the instant message is **OK** because they have granted access??

Comment: this is also no problem with the js sdk. with php, the whole login/reauthorization process is a LOT harder to handle.

Comment: btw, where does facebook state that you should use the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

The best route would be to use both, together. Some users might have javascript disabled or you might do something within your javascript code that will not work on some browsers. So as a fallback method you can use php api.

Going with only php would be solid and will work regardless of what the users client is, but you can make the user experience better with javascript.

Still, in most cases you'll end up having to use both.

Answer (score 0):

I have just spent the afternoon playing with the JavaScript SDK for **facebook** and I have to admit I think this is going to be the best option **for what I need**.

If anyone else is reading this, it may not be perfect for you - but with the way my application has been built I think it is a perfect fit. **Here is why :**

My standard login system uses *JavaScript* to grab my form data, then validate, which then passes the validated data via *AJAX* to a *PHP* validation script. Which in turn returns a *JSON* response to the original *AJAX* call. If my call comes back with `"ok" : true` then we are good to go basically.

The way the **facebook JavaScript SDK** works is almost a perfect little jigsaw puzzle to bolt onto the system I am using. All I require is a little bit of profile data, to then keep a record of this user on my system. THIS is provided by facebook, then validated by myself.

**However,** other social network logins may not be as nice and simple to use as the facebook API, so I could end up changing my mind on the overall system. **For now just using facebook,** I think the JavaScript SDK is absolutely spot on, as it just gets the information for you to run through your own validation on site. **As I said** this is a perfect fit **for my system** however it may not be for yours.